# How to send 2 values with href?

Tags: php, html, href

I am trying to send 2 values throughout the href. If I send one value, for example - id, everything is fine.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="options" name="options" method="post">                      
    <option value="opt1">Option one</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option two</option>
    <option value="opt3">Option three</option>
</select>
<br>
<a href="cart.php?action=update&id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
    <span class="btn btn-success">Change</span>
</a>
```

`$row` has my fetched data, so I get my id from there. I would also like to send a value which is chosen in a drop down list. I would send those values to this:

```
if($_GET["action"] == "update") {
    $stat = $_GET['options'];
    $itemID = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE orders
    SET status = '$stat'
    WHERE id = '$itemID'";
    $connect->query($sql);
    header("location:index.php?status=1");
}
```

Yet my `$stat` has nothing in it.

I tried almost every possible solution on the internet and non of them solved my problem.

Comment: You will have to write some javascript to get the selected info and add it to the href. Or use a form instead of an anchor

Comment: You are getting dynamically $row['id'] from PHP and you can print easily to href but your options can change by user. So you need to use Javascript to update your href.

Comment: **WARNING**: You are open to SQL injection. Please use [prepared statemets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust user input or pass POST/GET directly to a query.

Comment: What exact solution have you tried? What are you trying to send? The selection on the list? What is $row? How are you trying to read it? In case you try to read multipe choices, then your $stat will be an array, this is why you can't directly print the content

Comment: _“Yet my $stat has nothing in it.”_ - of course it doesn’t, because you did not actually submit your form (that the select field is part of), you _just_ clicked on a link instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work in your situation you need to use a FORM with a GET method. Not a method on a select element.

```php
<form method="GET" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <select id="options" name="options">                      
        <option value="opt1">Option one</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option two</option>
        <option value="opt3">Option three</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Change</button>
</form>
```

Selecting option 1 will submit to `cart.php?action=update&id=1&options=opt1`.

Another option is to use POST:

```php
<form method="POST" action="cart.php?action=update&id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <select id="options" name="options">                      
        <option value="opt1">Option one</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option two</option>
        <option value="opt3">Option three</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Change</button>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP:

```php
$action = $_POST['action'];
$options = $_POST['options'];
//etc
```

Keep in mind you are **vulnerable** to SQL injection and should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked for me!!

Answer (score -1):

your using the post method so instead of $_GET use $_POST and you should first connect with the database before writing anything into it. It's probably also smarter too use a form tag for these kinds of things, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp . hope I helped u

Comment: I dont see anywhere that suggests the OP is using POST. Certainly not when using an Anchor

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP has a ``method="post"`` on their select element for some reason.

Comment: @mikeroq As far as I am aware there is no `method` attribute on a `<select>` so thats just noise [The HTML Select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Correct that is a mistake on OP.

Answer (score -1):

This are the two errors in your code, the method you are using is **post method not get**, and the other is that you dont have a form to do that method, you need to create the select as a form to work properly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the quotation marks. Also there is no form element and you cannot put a method on an select element. This does nothing to solve their problem.

Comment: Right, I hadn't noticed that